# Word/phrase meaning snobby or "special elites" dominate area of expertise

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to find the appropriate word choice for the following:

> Whereas bench-depth for "topic ABC" used to be very strong in years
> past, recent years exhibit ________.

I had initially considered "a concentration of expertise" but that seems too neutral. I think the important thing here is that the word/phrase should specify that there is a selection bias at work. The normal, agreeable people have all self-selected to leave this field of study. That leaves those who remain are all very pompous and elitist.

I'm sure I could just explain along those lines and be done with it, but I can't suppress the part of me that wants to convey this in one elegant sentence.

Comment: You could just leave it at pompous and elitist.

Comment: Or perhaps another way to phrase the question is: word meaning tendency for people/something to grow more pompous over time